# AAC Codec Library (libFAAC alternative)

Tags: audio, aac

I'm looking for an AAC encoder/decoder library that works on Linux and Windows (for a C\C++ app). This is for a commercial product, so libFAAC is not an option. I've looked at the one from Nero and MainConcept, but I'd prefer something with a LGPL license or the like that doesn't require license fees.

Answer (score 4):

You may want to consider android's stagefright, though it will probably take some work to adapt to a general purpose library. It available is under the Apache 2.0 license https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/froyo-release/media/libstagefright/codecs

The 3GPP 26.410 AAC reference code is very high quality for reference code though they don't mention any specific licensing terms in their package http://www.3gpp.org/ftp/Specs/html-info/26410.htm

FFmpeg has a very fast LGPL AAC decoder and an experimental LGPL AAC encoder. The decoder is great but the encoder really sucks. http://git.ffmpeg.org/?p=ffmpeg;a=tree;f=libavcodec

Comment: still android is very poor for audio & video streaming

Answer (score 0):

FAAD2 is great AAC decoder: http://www.audiocoding.com/faad2.html

On the *encoder* side of things - no good LGPL implementation is available, you'd have to go with commercial encoders.

Comment: FAAD2 is GPL as well