# FFmpeg native AAC decoder

Tags: c++, c, ffmpeg, aac

I'm working on a commercial C\C++ app on Windows that need to decode AAC. I have looked at this question [AAC Codec Library (libFAAC alternative)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4608190/aac-codec-library-libfaac-alternative/9312842#9312842)
From the answer, it seems that FFmpeg has a native LGPL AAC decoder. However, when I looked at FFmpeg home page, I found no information about this decoder or what AAC object type it supports (only information about encoder). I have been searching for this for 2 days but I found almost nothing. So my questions are:

1. What type of object type does native FFmpeg AAC decoder support or does it even exist?
2. If the above decoder does not exist then is there any alternative free library? I have also looked at FDK AAC but I don't understand its license, can I use it for commercial product?

Please help I'm new to audio codec.

Comment: "aac packets" I presume :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What type of object type does native FFmpeg AAC decoder support or
>   does it even exist?

I have no idea what that means. I don't think this is proper English.

I'm going to assume that your question is: does FFmpeg include a native, LGPLv2.1 AAC decoder, and if so, what bitstream features does it support? The answer to the first question is yes. It's located [here](http://git.videolan.org/?p=ffmpeg.git;a=blob;f=libavcodec/aacdec.c;h=c0364033d645efe7b60f7223868ca27b90f797f7;hb=HEAD) in the codebase. Supported features are listed [here](http://git.videolan.org/?p=ffmpeg.git;a=blob;f=libavcodec/aacdec_template.c;h=2f270bcb191a4a490d9ad98ac7aad5ce7db851b5;hb=HEAD#l43) (although that list is likely somewhat outdated). If you have more specific questions about supported bitstream features, ask here and I'll see what I can remember.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. About the question, I'm sorry, English is not my native language, writing the question is a bit hard. I mean list of  Audio Object Types it support ( MPEG-2 and MPEG-4 AAC LC etc). FDK AAC decoder has a list like that in the wiki https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fraunhofer_FDK_AAC. I don't know much about audio codec, does that mean each audio object type have different bitstream features, and to decode I have to set the correct value. Do I have to dig deep into AAC specification to understand this?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you're looking for http://git.videolan.org/?p=ffmpeg.git;a=blob;f=libavcodec/aacdec_template.c;h=2f270bcb191a4a490d9ad98ac7aad5ce7db851b5;hb=HEAD#l43 - you don't have to set anything, just the extradata in AVCodecContext, which is the ESDS atom in the m4a file. If you use ffmpeg's demuxer, this is all automatic. In short, ffmpeg's AAC decoder supports all popular/widespread features used in the wild (heaacv1, heaacv2, aac+, etc.).

Comment: Is there any official document for this? My customer insist on knowing the support list. I would be thankful if you could give me some instructions to learn it.

Comment: The official document is the list in the source code.

Comment: Thank you, it's very nice of you to answer my question. I'll look more into those features.